# anbox: snap is unusable due to missing files

Tags: linux, fedora, android, snap

I cannot get anbox to install:

```
$ sudo snap install --devmode --beta anbox
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "anbox" (186) (snap is unusable due to missing files; contact developer)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm having this problem with every of my snaps today under fedora. So it's a fedora problem related problem since it's working great under ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answer resides in this thread that I've just found out about:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-install-snap-file-snap-is-unusable-due-to-missing-files/25719

The new unsquashfs update that you've probably installed 2 days ago gives a bug into the new snap package. We need an update as notified in the thread of snapd

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me - showing me that I had to upgrade snap. But I am on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and that was not that straightforward. In my case I had to uninstall snap and then remove the repo, add the repo again, reboot, install snapd and then installed what I needed - which went without an issue ... but the downside is that I lost all installed snaps and had to install them again :D